# Google AppEngine sending all requests to same instance

Tags: google-app-engine, latency

Lately, I have seen GAE taking much, much longer to process requests than it did just a week ago.  Nothing changed in my code, but GAE now is taking 4000-12000ms to respond to requests.  What makes is worse is that I have plenty of instances available with 0 requests on them.
Has anyone else seen this happen?
What can I do to fix it?I have gone as far as to spin up 15 extra instances (and paid through the nose for them) but nothing seems to send requests to the other idle instances reliably.
My bill has gone from 70-90c/day to $5-8/day without any code change or increase in traffic.  In fact, I am losing traffic because of the huge latency.

```
    QPS*    Latency*    Requests    Errors  Age Memory  Availability
    0.000   0.0 ms  1378    0   10:10:09    57.9 MBytes Dynamic
    0.000   0.0 ms  1681    0   15:39:57    57.2 MBytes Dynamic
    0.017   9687.0 ms   886 0   10:19:10    56.7 MBytes Dynamic
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing AppStats to get a picture of what's taking so long in each request.  I'd guess that you're having some contention issues or large numbers of reads/writes caused by some new data configuration.

The idle instances won't help decrease latency - it looks like every request takes a long time, and with less than one request per minute (in this sample anyway), 10s requests could run serially on the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem in our app. In our case, we are under the impression that GAE's scheduler did a poor job in balancing requests to existing instances.

In some cases, the scheduler decided to spin up new instances instead of re-using already existing ones. Since spinning a new instance took 5 to >45 seconds, I suspect this might be what happened to you.

Try to investigate the following and see if it helps you:

1. **Make sure your app has thread-safe enabled** so that you could process concurrent requests. You could configure this in your [app.yaml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests) if you are using Python, or in your [appengine-web.xml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests) if you use Java. Of course, you also need to make sure that the code in your app is threadsafe.
2. In your application settings, if it is still set on automatic, **change the minimum pending latency to a non-automatic setting.** I'd suggest around 10 seconds for now, but you could experiment later on which setting would suit you the most. This force the scheduler to wait for a certain time to see if any instance is available within the time before spinning up a new instance.

Now, to answer your original question regarding `sending all requests to same instance`, as far as I know there is no way to address a specific front-end instance in order to direct the requests to that particular instance.

What you could do is migrate your app to use backend instances instead of the regular frontend instance. Backends provides a way to [directly target any particular instance within it](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html#Addressing_Backends). You could deploy your app in a single backend to have more control on the number of instance that you spawn. And since using the backend bypass the scheduler, you would not encounter latencies caused by new instances spinning up.

The major drawback of using this approach is that you lose the auto-scalability benefit of using front-end instances. But seeing from your low daily billing, I think scalability is not yet a major concern for the scale of your app.